# How to expire page in PHP when user logout

Tags: php, logout

I want to expire my previous page when end user clicks on **LogOut** or **Back button** of the browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you include this at the top of all of your pages, it will require the client to always reload the content, making the back-button requesting a new copy of the page.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: It does work on localhosst and remote for me. 
You should inspect HTTP headers using firebug, or a debugging proxy like fiddler.

Comment: This should work, unless your computer time is actually before 26th of July, 1997. Make sure you are also destroying the user session.

Answer (score 0):

Destroy the session key with `session_destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

You could have some issues with the browser back button, because when clicked, some browsers simply don't reload the page from the server and displays the previous state of the page from the cache.